# PHP mysql_result() but its now deleted need sometihng to replace it and its premetrs should be to run my program, cuz this mysql_result line

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)) {
    //following an old tutorial
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `Username`='$username' AND `Password`='$password_hash'";

    if($query_run= mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
            //tried most of solutions on the site not working
        if ($query_num_rows==0) {
            echo 'Invalid username/password combination';
        }
        else if ($query_num_rows==1) {
            //need sometihng to substitute the mysql_result
            //its not working and iam not kinda ahnde with php
            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');;
            $_SESSTION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header ('Location: php.php');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not pastebin, please put some effort into your question/spelling/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

mysql has been depricated, use mysqli instead
You can use this code to get data:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password_hash'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
        echo "id:" . $row["id"];
   }
} else {
   echo "No results found";
}
```

Comment: iam convencied with your answer but my programing giving unexpected end an new error

Comment: $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `Username`='$username' AND `Password`='$password_hash'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result==0)){
  echo 'Invalid username/password combination';
  
 }else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $user_id = "id:" . $row["id"];
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
  header ('Location: PHP.php');
   }
  }  //stuck here now with that error